# ShowDialog stalls with .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, .net-core, mocking

I am upgrading from .NET Framework to .NET Core and I am having a problem with `ShowDialog`. With .NET Framework and unit testing the `ShowDialog` hits the command and keeps right on processing but with .NET Core the `ShowDialog` starts a new thread and stays there until a button is selected manually. This can't work with a unit test.

This line of code:

```
tabControl.SelectTabItem(1); // FlaUI command
```

causes the popup window to be displayed but I need to select a grid item and an Ok button. My question is how to not stall on the `ShowDialog` action?

This is a picture of the Dialog box:
[image]

The Unit test is in it's own project and calls the dialog box in another project as shown:

```
       tableSelection = new DatabaseTableSelection(filePath, contr);
       tableSelection.Topmost = true;
       tableSelection.ShowDialog();
       if (tableSelection.selectedTable == null)
       {
          return false;
       }
```

It seems that I need to Mock this but I have never used mock before. Any ideas?

Comment: You'd need to click that ok button on the dialogue somehow.  DIfferent test runner. Different results. Your ui might have to be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `ShowDialog` in any method being unit-tested, nor any other kind of dialogs or UI.

A possible workaround is to inject a interface, something like `IMessageDialog`, that can be mocked in unit tests.

As an example:

```
public interface IDatabaseTableDialog
{
    bool ShowTable(string filepath, Control parentControl);
}
public class MockDatabaseTableDialog : IDatabaseTableDialog
{
    public bool ShowTable(string filepath, Control parentControl) => true;
}
public class DatabaseTableDialog : IDatabaseTableDialog
{
    public bool ShowTable(string filepath, Control parentControl)
    {
        var tableSelection = new DatabaseTableSelection(filepath, parentControl);
        tableSelection.Topmost = true;
        tableSelection.ShowDialog();
        if (tableSelection.selectedTable == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that mocks tend to be easier if you can encapsulate all functionality to a single method. Otherwise you might need two interfaces, one for creating your dialog, and one for the dialog itself.

But the more complex the UI is used the more complex the mocks become, and this makes unit tests slower to write and less valuable.

So the approach I tend to use is to ensure ShowDialog, or any other kind of UI is restricted to specific UI classes, or the viewModel, and try to move any complex logic away from these classes. That way it is possible to test the complex logic with unit tests, and do manual testing to check that the UI works as it is supposed to. There are tools for automated UI tests, but I have not seen one yet that I think are worth the effort.

Comment: Why did this work in .Net Framework  but not in .NET Core?

Comment: @JosephGabello I have no idea. But it does not matter, if your automated tests start showing dialogs you have a buggy test. At least unless you use a framework specifically designed to test UIs.

Comment: Unfortunately my dialog box looks like this picture: [link](Screenshot 2023-02-01 152131.png)

Comment: Unfortunately my dislog has 3 buttons and grid selection on it.  I don't know how to make it an IMessageDialog.

Comment: @JosephGabello How do you interface with your dialog? What methods//properties do you use? Make an interface with the same things. Some refactoring tools have an "extract interface" functions that lets you just check what methods/properties you want from a list.

Comment: I have added more comments in the main section to better define my problem.  I understand it seems I need to mock this but the form is in a different project and calls are made to that project when a new TAB item is selected.  Any ideas on how to mock this?

Comment: @JosephGabello added an example. But as I mentioned, *try to seprate UI from logic*. Use unit tests where they save more time than they take to write. Complicated things like math is often most valuable to unit test, since it is easy to make errors, and there is often a clearly defined "right" result. UI is less valuable, since problems are often more subjective, and subject to more frequent changes.